# how to call two endpoints in one sequence in wso2 esb?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have 2 apis for 2 insurance companies: car-insurance-company-1 and car-insurance-company-2.
these two take a json data and give me the price of car insurance.
i want to call them both at the same time via an api deployed in wso2 esb.my client needs to get the price of both companies and compare them.
for example the input is: `{"type":"Ford","model":"EcoSport"}`

and the output is `{"company":"company1","price":"1000$"},{"company":"company2","price":"2000$"}`

simply speaking i want to call two Endpoints at the same time, in one sequence.i am using wso2 esb 5.

how can i do it?
is there another way?
thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should use is Enterprise Integration Pattern called: Scatter-Gather

In this [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationPatterns/Scatter-Gather) is described that pattern with wso2 examples. Also the Split-aggregate described in [WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Split-Aggregate+Pattern+) should be helpful. That is all what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I used clone mediator to call both apis and aggregate to append the results based on this : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354010/aggregate-multiple-json-responses-with-aggregate-mediator-in-wso2-esb)

Comment: Yes, that explanation from this link, fits to your issue.